# Cannot Deploy Pyramid Application on Heroku

Tags: python, heroku, pyramid

I am having issues deploying my Pyramid app on Heroku. It runs fine locally but as soon as I try to launch it I receive this error "pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: mymedaproject". mymedaproject is the name of my project and is not a python library which is why I am confused. I followed the instructions from this recipe to get to this point:

http://pyramid-cookbook.readthedocs.org/en/latest/deployment/heroku.html

Any ideas?
[image]

Comment: runs fine local with Foreman or pserve & waitress???

Answer (score 1):

May be you forgot to put your python project `mymedaproject` in development mode. What follows is the relevant part of the cookbook recipe.

Create a `Procfile`

```
$ echo "web: ./run" > Procfile
```

Create `run` with the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
python setup.py develop
python runapp.py
```

The first line puts your python project in development mode and enables Paste to load it using your INI file. Make sure Procfile, run, runapp.py and setup.py are in same directory.

References

- [Getting Started with Python on Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-python#declare-process-types-with-procfile)
- [Process Types and the Procfile](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile)

Optimization

running a script using a Procfile should work without making it executable

```
$ echo "web: sh ./run" > Procfile
```

Comment: a little confusion to clear do we need to create a run file and add the above two lines or if so what to do in the runapp.py . Please make me clear on this Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check your `.gitignore` file that it isn't blocking any `egg` or `egg-info` information.

If it is, Heroku won't be receiving the egg for your application.